# Destroy activity Issues in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi I am using the button for bottom tab bar in android like iphone. I have three screens and showing three button in all the screens. I used the below coding for each button in each screen.

```
Intent intentNavOne = new Intent(ScreenOne.this,
                    ScreenTwo.class);
            intentNavOne .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intentNavOne .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

            intentNavOne .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intentNavOne );
```

Now the problem is some times the flow of the navigation changed. I just want the solution. Any alternate way to achive my task.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Call `finish()` in the activity where you are starting the new activity, this will stop the lifecycle of that activity.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer I have faced same problem that you are facing now with the `buttons` to show tabs as in iphone and finally I switched to `tabbars` of android.

I would suggest you that use `tabbars` instead of `buttons` as navigation will be very smooth you do not have to bother about previous `activity`.

check below links for creating `tabbars` in android they are good tutorials

[link 1](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-tab-bar-example-1/)

[link2 for action bars for 3.0 and above](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-action-bar-tab-menu-example)

let me know if you have more problems